# Translate signature generation code from PHP to Javascript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm using the zoom.us API and I need to generate a signature in the server side for the web client. They only provide a PHP example of how to do it. Can someone translate this code to Javascript so I can use it in my nodejs server?

```
//PHP example code
function generate_signature ( $api_key, $api_sercet, $meeting_number, $role){

  $time = time() * 1000; //time in milliseconds (or close enough)

  $data = base64_encode($api_key . $meeting_number . $time . $role);

  $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $api_sercet, true);

  $_sig = $api_key . "." . $meeting_number . "." . $time . "." . $role . "." . base64_encode($hash);

  //return signature, url safe base64 encoded
  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($_sig), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

Comment: why you are using ajax to get the result from php to javascript?

Comment: *Can someone translate this code to Javascript* most likely if you pay them.  SO is a site to help people with coding problems more than a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

```
const crypto = require('crypto') // crypto comes with Node.js

function generateSignature(apiKey, apiSecret, meetingNumber, role) {

  // Prevent time sync issue between client signature generation and zoom 
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime() - 30000
  const msg = Buffer.from(apiKey + meetingNumber + timestamp + role).toString('base64')
  const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(msg).digest('base64')
  const signature = Buffer.from(`${apiKey}.${meetingNumber}.${timestamp}.${role}.${hash}`).toString('base64')

  return signature
}

// pass in your Zoom JWT API Key, Zoom JWT API Secret, Zoom Meeting Number, and 0 to join meeting or webinar or 1 to start meeting
console.log(generateSignature(process.env.API_KEY, process.env.API_SECRET, 123456789, 0))
```